# Die Grenze »zu« oder »nach« einem Land?

Tags: preposition

Bei Duden heißt es:

> der Fluss bildet die Grenze *zu* Polen.

aber auch

> an der Grenze *nach* Bayern.

Welche grammatikalischen Regeln greifen hier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Im Prinzip kann man in den meisten Fällen beides sagen, allerdings ist mit der

> Grenze *nach* Polen

eher der Grenz*übergang* mit dem Grenz*übertritt* gemeint ("nach" intendiert eine Bewegung)

und mit der

> Grenze *zu* Polen

eher die Grenz*linie* (Landkarte, Zaun, usw.), hier ist i.A. keine Bewegung involviert.

Man würde also eher

> Im Dezember überschritt Hannibal die Grenze nach Italien

und

> Die Elbe bildet die Grenze zu Polen

sagen.

Answer (score 3):

### Kurze Antwort:

Wenn das Land ohne Artikel verwendet wird (Polen, Ungarn, ...) kann man beide Präpositionen verwenden:

> Die Grenze nach Polen.
>   Die Grenze nach Ungarn.
>   Die Grenze zu Polen.
>   Die Grenze zu Ungarn.

Bei Ländern, die einen Artikel haben (die Schweiz, der Iran), kann man nur »zu« + Artikel verwenden:

> Die Grenze zur Schweiz.
>   Die Grenze zum Iran.

---

### Lange Antwort:

Obwohl hier keine Bewegung stattfindet, werden die Sätze in beiden Fällen so konstruiert, als läge eine auf ein Ziel gerichtete Bewegung vor.

> Ich gehe **zu** dem Fest. (zu + Dativ; wohin?)
>   Ich gehe **nach** Innsbruck. (nach + Dativ; wohin?)

(Den Dativ im zweiten Satz erkennt man z.B. durch eine Attributierung des Objekts: »Ich gehe **nach** meinem Innsbruck.«)

Andere Sprachen haben für eine Bewegung auf ein Ziel zu einen eigenen Fall, den Allativ, im Deutschen muss eine solche Bewegung mit Präpositionen gebildet werden. Diese Präpositionen verlangen, dass das Ziel in einem bestimmten grammatischen Fall verwendet wird, der von der Präposition abhängt.

Details kann man unter anderem hier nachlesen: http://mein-deutschbuch.de/lokale-praepositionen.html

### nach

Die Präposition »nach« kann mit Namen von Städten, Ländern, Kontinenten usw. verwendet werden wenn diese Ortsnamen üblicherweise ohne Artikel verwendet werden (nach Mainz, nach Ungarn, nach Afrika), aber auch mit Richtungen (nach Süden, nach Hause, nach rechts). Für Ortsnamen, die man mit Artikel verwendet werden (die Schweiz, der Irak) eignet sich die Präposition »nach« nicht.

Weil auch die Richtungen ohne Artikel verwendet werden, wird »nach« immer ohne Artikel verwendet.

### zu

Die Präposition »zu« wird bei Bewegungen verwendet, deren Ziel eine Person ist (Ich gehe zu Anna), dabei wird kein Artikel verwendet. Aber auch Orte können mit »zu« verwendet werden, hier aber immer mit Artikel, wobei die beiden infrage kommenden Singular-Artikel »der« und »dem« mit »zu« zu »zur« bzw. »zum« verschmelzen. Nur der Plural-Artikel »den« wird nicht verschmolzen (»zu den«)

> Ich gehe zur Schule.
>   Ich gehe zum Bäcker.
>   Ich gehe zu den sieben Eichen.

---

Wenn es nun aber um Grenzen geht, ist das »Ziel« fast immer ein Land. Daher kann »nach« immer bedenkenlos verwendet werden, wenn das Land auch sonst ohne Artikel verwendet wird:

> Die Grenze nach Italien.
>   Die Grenze nach Bayern.

Verlangt ein Land einen Artikel, ist die Verwendung von »nach« nicht angebracht. Hier muss »zu« verwendet werden:

> Die Grenze zur Schweiz.
>   Die Grenze zum Vatikan.
>   Die Grenze zu den Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika.

Im Gegensatz zu den tatsächlichen Bewegungen kann »zu« im Grenz-Fall auch bei Ländern ohne Artikel verwendet werden, dann aber auch hier ohne Artikel:

> Die Grenze zu Italien.
>   Die Grenze zu Bayern.

Comment: [Ich sehe jetzt nicht, warum die Grenze »nach der Schweiz« verboten sein sollte.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nach+der+Schweiz%2Cin+die+Schweiz%2C+zur+Schweiz&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnach%20der%20Schweiz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20die%20Schweiz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czur%20Schweiz%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Jan In diesem Artikel auf Spiegel haben sie so einen Satz "Bei Wodka und Zigaretten werden daher abends Pläne geschmiedet, wie man sich dem deutschen Kommißstiefel durch einen Gang über **die grüne Grenze nach der Slowakei** entziehen könnte." link: http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-44449558.html

Comment: @Jan Weil keiner weiß, was nach der Schweiz sein wird.

Comment: @Em1 Nimm dir kurz die Zeit und sichte die [von Google Books gelieferten Fundstellen von *nach der Schweiz*](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22nach+der+schweiz%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_de&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=Ujv9V5e2CKag6AS5-JbwAw).

Comment: @Jan Done. Meinung nicht geändert.

Comment: @Jan [Im direkten Vergleich zwischen *in die Schweiz* und *nach der Schweiz*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+die+Schweiz%2Cnach+der+Schweiz&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20die%20Schweiz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnach%20der%20Schweiz%3B%2Cc0) erkennt man aber, warum Leuten unter 60 *nach der Schweiz* etwas komisch vorkommt.

Comment: @Raketenolli Was umso mehr meine Behauptung untermauert, dass *nach der Schweiz* mitnichten verboten ist. Es mag lediglich aus der Mode gekommen sein. =)

Answer (score 0):

Du kannst beide Präpositionen benutzen, wenn du eine Richtung meinst.

> Das Land hat eine Grenze zu Deutschland.
>   Das Land hat eine Grenze nach Deutschland.

Zusätzlich dazu kannst du auch sagen:

> Das Land grenzt an Deutschland.

Wenn du meinst, dass ein Land eine Grenze mit Deutschland teilt, kannst du auch sagen:

> Das Land hat eine Grenze mit Deutschland.